# Python concurrent.futures Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs: OSError: handle is closed only running in Visual studio Debugging Mode

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I trying to implement the concurrent.futures have been having an issue, I generated a code that when executed in:

- Python Terminal
- ```
  Enters in some infinite loop in my last loop and do not finish the code, this code below do finish, however reproduces the error thgat i receive in the Debug Mode below
  ```
- So when I run it in Visual Studio Code Debug Mode
- Generates the folowing error:

  ```
  Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\debor\anaconda3\envs\multimidia_image\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 102, in _python_exit
      thread_wakeup.wakeup()
    File "C:\Users\debor\anaconda3\envs\multimidia_image\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 90, in wakeup
      self._writer.send_bytes(b"")
    File "C:\Users\debor\anaconda3\envs\multimidia_image\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 183, in send_bytes
      self._check_closed()
    File "C:\Users\debor\anaconda3\envs\multimidia_image\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 136, in _check_closed
      raise OSError("handle is closed")
  OSError: handle is closed
  ```

This code reproduces the error in the Debug Mode:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import concurrent.futures
import multiprocessing
from itertools import product



def main_execucao(n_exec,input_n_geracoes_max,tipo_apt,input_pop_0,tipo_pop_gerar,tipo_selecao_crossover,tour,tipo_crossover,input_p_cross,tipo_mutacao,tipo_reinsercao,words):

    # Dicionário vazio para armazenar resultados por geração n+1
    resultados = {}
    resultados[("teste")] = [1,0]
    return resultados


def main(): 

    # Parametros problemáticos Process
    tmi = ["tm1"]
    si = ["s1"]
    ci = ["c1"]
    ri = ["r2"]

    # Lista de variantes
    variantes = list(product(*[tmi, si, ci, ri]))

    # Numero de execuções
    input_n_execucoes = 3
    

    # Inputs para main

    # Inputs gerais

    # Lista iterável para chamar função
    lista_n_exec=range(0,input_n_execucoes)

    # Numero de gerações
    input_n_geracoes_max =  [50] * len(lista_n_exec)

    # Palavras
    w_1=np.flip(np.array(list("send")),0)
    w_2=np.flip(np.array(list("more")),0)
    w_3=np.flip(np.array(list("money")),0)
    words=[w_1,w_2,w_3]
    words_lista=[words]* len(lista_n_exec)

    for param in variantes:

        # Inputs parameters
    
        # Tipo aptidao (apt_1= aptidão simples, apt_2 aptidão invertida, apt_3 invertida normalizada pior valor)
        tipo_apt = "apt_1"
        tipo_apt_lista = [tipo_apt] * len(lista_n_exec)

        # População inicial

        input_pop_0 = [100] * len(lista_n_exec)

        tipo_pop_gerar = ["sem_repeticao_populacao_inicial"] * len(lista_n_exec)


        nome_selecao_cross  =param[1]
        tipo_selecao_crossover = [nome_selecao_cross] * len(lista_n_exec)
        tour = [3] * len(lista_n_exec)# Apenas se seleção for torneio 

        # Tipo de crossover

        nome_cross = param[2]
        tipo_crossover = [nome_cross] * len(lista_n_exec)
        # % de Crossover
        input_p_cross = [0.8] * len(lista_n_exec)

        # % de mutação

        nome_mutacao = param[0]
        if nome_mutacao=="tm1":
            perc_mutacao=0.02
        elif nome_mutacao=="tm2":
            perc_mutacao=0.10
        elif nome_mutacao=="tm3":
            perc_mutacao=0.2

        tipo_mutacao = [perc_mutacao] * len(lista_n_exec)

        # Tipo de reinserção

        nome_reinsercao = param[3]
        tipo_reinsercao = [nome_reinsercao] * len(lista_n_exec)

        # Finaliza inputs

        # Index contar número de execuções e gerações
        ix_exec_real=0
        ger_exec_real=0

        # Número total de convergencias após todas execuções 
        total_conv_tds_exec=0

        # Dicionário para armazenar resultados de todas as n execuções
        results={}

        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:

            for result in (executor.map(main_execucao,lista_n_exec,input_n_geracoes_max,tipo_apt_lista,input_pop_0,tipo_pop_gerar,tipo_selecao_crossover,tour,tipo_crossover,input_p_cross,tipo_mutacao,tipo_reinsercao,words_lista)):
                results.update(result)
            
            print("finish")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    main()
```

Do anyone have a clue of what i can try?
I have found a similar issue:
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/issues/423

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Minimal Reproducible Example of your Code

Comment: It's a bug in python/unix. Just update to python 3.9 to solve this issue.

Comment: @Savrige what do those of use who cannot upgrade to 3.9 do?

Answer (score 3):

Per [#434](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-python/pull/434),

> Python Standard Library - concurrent.futures used thread to manage
> tasks queue, therefore when sentry patched start method of Thread, it
> will cause reference cycle and prevent gc from collecting.
>
> So in concurrent.futures.process, the _queue_management_thread in
> _threads_wakeups will be discarded until running a full gc collection, if not, exception will be raise when python exited, because the actual
> manage thread has already stopped.

The fix can be found there, permitting one to manually input it into their Python 3.8 rather than upgrading to Python 3.9.

Comment: The mentioned fix looks specific to Sentry's code. It is unclear how this could be applied to fixing the mentioned issue in general, or whether it helps pinpoint the underlying issue.

Answer (score 2):

See if the problem goes away by switching from using the `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` class  to using the `multiprocess.pool.Pool` class by changing two lines:

Change from:

```py
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:

            for result in (executor.map(main_execucao,lista_n_exec,input_n_geracoes_max,tipo_apt_lista,input_pop_0,tipo_pop_gerar,tipo_selecao_crossover,tour,tipo_crossover,input_p_cross,tipo_mutacao,tipo_reinsercao,words_lista)):
```

To:

```py
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as executor:


            for result in (executor.starmap(main_execucao,zip(lista_n_exec,input_n_geracoes_max,tipo_apt_lista,input_pop_0,tipo_pop_gerar,tipo_selecao_crossover,tour,tipo_crossover,input_p_cross,tipo_mutacao,tipo_reinsercao,words_lista))):
```

You can also, of course, now remove the `import concurrent.futures` statement.

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking for an answer to why the `OSError: handle is closed` error occurs, not a work-around

Comment: The comment offered by @Savrige offered an explanation. I, unfortunately, am not in a position to verify that. But *if* that is an accurate assessment, you either upgrade to Python 3.9 or you do a workaround.

Comment: Since Python 3.9 fixed the issue, someone identified what was causing the problem. I would like to know what is causing the problem. Savrige just said "it's a bug". What is the bug? Where is it? Why did it occur? What change was performed to fix it?

Comment: I would suggest then that you update your question in hopes of getting the type of response you seek.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that.